# Logging in breaks OS

Tags: 20.04, graphics, intel-graphics, 20.10

I just made my installation media for kubuntu 20.04 LTS, and booted into it. I was unable to get into the live USB without choosing the (safe graphics) option, then, after restarting the device, I was able to get to the login screen without any problems, but once I do login, the whole thing freezes, and a notification appears in the bottom right saying "Desktop effects were restarted due to a graphics reset"

I already tried using other flavors of Ubuntu, and even Linux mint refused to work.

(Edit)

I also completely forgot to mention that the machine also has windows 10 installed, and is being configured for dual-boot.

Processor: Intel Core i5-3470

Graphics: Intel(R) HD Graphics

SSD: PNY CS900 480GB SSD, which holds kubuntu, the bootloader, and windows 10.

HDD: 1TB WDC WD10EZEX-08WN4A0 (WD Blue). Only one data partition which is formatted as NTFS.

Motherboard: MSI B75A-G41 (MS-7758), BIOS version 17.8

(Edit #2)

Tried both kernel v5.10 and v5.10.12, still unable to  get to desktop without disabling video driver loading.

Comment: Could you update your question to list some rather important details, such as the brand and model of computer you're using? If it's a custom-built machine, could you specify which CPU, motherboard, video card, and storage devices you're using? This will make it less challenging to provide specific support on how to overcome these issues 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had the BIOS set to use PCIe graphics while I was using integrated graphics, which after setting it from PEG to IGD fixed the issue.

In my case I had to go through "MSI mainboard settings > Advanced > Integrated graphics configuration" in the BIOS and set it to "IGD"

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

MSI B75A-G41 (MS-7758)

<strike>It appears that you have a very old BIOS version 3.0.</strike> Confirm with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. There's a newer BIOS, version 17.8, available [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B75A-G41.html).

How to flash BIOS .pdf document is [here](https://storage-asset.msi.com/files/pdf/How_to_flash_the_BIOS.pdf).

How to use M-FLASH to update BIOS video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRyFMf0D9Lc).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**disks**

re: "*1TB WDC WD10EZEX-08WN4A0 (WD Blue). Only one data partition which is formatted as exFAT.*"

If you're planning on sharing files with Windows, NTFS would be a better choice.

re: "*PNY CS900 480GB SSD*"

Confirm that you have current firmware installed in this SSD.

**video**

Your Intel(R) HD Graphics may require Kubuntu 20.10 to operate properly.

**Update #1:**

Regarding the video, as long as you're on 20.10 (not 20.04) you might try a newer kernel. Go to [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10) and try that kernel.

**Update #2:**

All flavors of Ubuntu and Kubuntu fail, as does Linux Mint. Suspect defective CPU or motherboard. You could try adding a discrete video card and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I apparently mistook the motherboard's version for the BIOS version. I am sorry for concerning you with that, I do have latest BIOS installed. Thanks for the tip, I did reformat my 1TB to NTFS, and the SSD does have latest firmware. I was also unable to get into Kubuntu 20.10's live session without entering with (safe graphics). Once Kubuntu 20.10 has been installed, I was still able to get to the login screen, but when I do login, the screen just turns black, without showing parts of the GUI like it used to do before. I did also select the "install updates while installing ubuntu" option.

Comment: @TIM As long as you're on 20.10 (not 20.04) you might try a newer kernel. Go to https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10/ and try that kernel.

Comment: Was able to get into the desktop using (nomodeset) in the grub boot options, tho I would prefer if it were to output 1080p instead of whatever resolution it outputs. I then tried the v5.10 kernel you linked to and the latest stable v5.10.12 mainline kernel, but still were unable to get into the desktop

Comment: @TIM nomodeset disables video drivers. You're sure you've got an Intel HD graphics card, and not also a Nvidia card built in? Try this. At the login screen, select your username, then go to the cogwheel icon, and select "Ubuntu on Wayland" and see if there's any change after then entering your password.

Comment: I tried the kernel, did the same thing as all the other ones. Yes I am certain that the Intel HD iGPU is the only GPU in the system. Also I was unable to find the cogwheel icon on kubuntu, tho I do remember that being present in ubuntu. Should I try installing ubuntu?

Comment: @TIM Interesting idea... you can probably just boot to a Ubuntu 20.10 USB flash key in "Try Ubuntu" mode to see if the problem also occurs in Ubuntu.

Comment: Tried live usb flash. same behaviour, proceeded to install ubuntu, and was unable to login with any of the kernels provided, neither normally nor on wayland. Proceeded to download and install mainline kernels 5.10, 5.10.12, and 5.11-rc5, and all of them do the same thing. When I login normally with ubuntu, the desktop gets loaded normally, but whenever I interact with anything, the desktop breaks, then the desktop environment restarts, but when I select wayland, the desktop never gets loaded and I get thrown onto a black screen. All kernels displayed the same behaviour.

Comment: @TIM You must have a defective CPU or motherboard. If you have a video card that you can plug into a slot, that might be instructive. Have we run `memtest`? Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I was fairly busy the last few days. I did run it overnight but never got around to actually posting the result until now. https://imgur.com/a/I7KhXcL

Comment: @TIM Did you have 2 or 4 memory DIMMs installed when you ran `memtest`?

Comment: I had two DIMMs installed

Comment: @TIM Thanks for running memtest. As I mentioned before... *"You must have a defective CPU or motherboard. If you have a video card that you can plug into a slot, that might be instructive"*. That's about all I can suggest at this point.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me out! I've lost a graphics card a few months back in a storage room, so i will try again if I do find it.